# How to find the steady state vector in matlab given a 3x3 matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am given a 3x3 matrix [0.4, 0.1, 0.2; 0.3, 0.7. 0.7; 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]. The question is to find the steady state vector. However, I am supposed to solve it using Matlab and I am having trouble getting the correct answer. We are supposed to use the formula A(x-I)=0. I can solve it by hand, but I am not sure how to input it into Matlab. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you meant `x(A-I)=0` since what you wrote doesn't really make sense to me. The equation I wrote implies that `x*A^n=x` which is what is usually meant by steady state. The solution to the equation is the left eigenvector of `A` with eigenvalue of `1`.

You can get the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of `A` using the [`eig`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) function.

```
A = [0.4, 0.1, 0.2; 0.3, 0.7, 0.7; 0.3, 0.2, 0.1];
% Get the eigenvalues (D) and left eigenvectors (W)
[~,D,W] = eig(A);
% Get the index of the eigenvalue closest to 1
[~,idx] = min(abs(diag(D)-1));
% Get associated eigenvector
x = W(:,idx).';
```

Checking the solution

```
>> all(abs(x*(A-eye(size(A)))) < 1e-10)
ans =
   logical
    1
```

Comment: Yes that is what I meant! Sorry was in too much of a hurry I guess. Anyways thank you so much for the explanation.